# How to handle NULL values when inserting with the Dataloader(.io)

Tags: data-loader, bulk-api

I'm uploading records with the amazing dataloader.io and have a hard time to upload some records with NO value for optional fields. What do I have to put in those fields?

- #N/A
- 'null'
- NULL
- ''
- ""
- 0

Is there a definite guide or reference document that answers this?

Answer (score 12):

Inserting null values is an option that you need to manually set for the api call. Once you set that option you just leave the cells empty and it will null out any fields where the cell is empty.

In dataloader.io you set this option here: [image: null setting]

That option is greyed out for me and from the dataloader.io discussion boards it looks like they haven't implemented this feature yet so you may have better luck using the regular dataloader to do this. With the regular data loader you do this here: [image]

Comment: I can't use the standard dataloader as it does not allow me to auto-relate fields like the dataloader.io does.

Comment: @RobertS You might want to look at the free informatica data loader. I know it has auto-mapping for fields/columns with the same name and supports inserting null values.

Comment: I can't use Informatica as I am on a Mac :-(

Comment: Does anybody know when Dataloader.io will support null values?!

Comment: @RobertS Have you tried Jitterbit data loader? I know it works on mac and I believe it supports auto-relation.

Comment: grigriforce: I just installed Jitterbit dataloader for Mac and couldnt find out how to do a auto relation there.