# How to make a field blank using dataloader

Tags: data-loader, field-update

I have an email field having some values. I want to make this field blank. The problem is I have to make this field blank for 1000 records. When I try to update the email with blank in data loader it does not update.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered already by sfdcfox here: [How to handle NULL values when inserting with the Dataloader(.io)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/how-to-handle-null-values-when-inserting-with-the-dataloader-io).

Go to **Settings** menu on Data Loader and check **Insert null values**.